How to fix "Transform with key of translateY must be a number" error in React Native?
I'm trying to postion an element correctly using transform property,
but whenever i give percentage values it giving me an error
How can I fix this issue ?
Here is my code
import { Animated,Image,View} from "react-native";

<Animated.View
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  right: 20,
                  top: "50%",
                  transform: [{ translateY: "-50%" }],
                }}
              >
                {captchaImage && (
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: captchaImage }}
                    style={{
                      width: 50,
                      height: 24,
                      resizeMode: "contain",
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </Animated.View>

Screenshot of simulator is attached below.
did anyone have faced similar issue ?


TranslateY cannot be a string. Make it a number.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms

when i hover around traslateY vs code gives me below values are acceptable
(property) translateY: number | ${number}% | Animated.Value | Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<string | number> | Animated.WithAnimatedObject<Animated.AnimatedNode>

how we can center something vertically if we cannot use percentages?

Regarding intellisense, that sounds like the inferred typing for Animated styles so worth exploring.

You can use flex and its properties to center its children. Also where is the animation happening?

TranslateY must be a number. If you want it to be 50% of screen height you can use something like this.


 import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
 
 const windowDimensions = Dimensions.get('window');

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 20,
        top: '50%',
        transform: [{translateY: windowDimensions.height * 0.5}],
      }}>
      {captchaImage && (
        <Image
          source={{uri: captchaImage}}
          style={{
            width: 50,
            height: 24,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
          }}
        />
      )}
    </Animated.View>
  );



For more info about Dimensions check out the link.
